# Combining where and IIF statements in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form with three buttons relating to three yes/no variables that are not mutually exclusive in a subform. By default Access sets up the relationship using "and" so if I select two of the three buttons it shows me all the observations that have "yes" for both, but I want the buttons to have an "or" relationship so that if I select two buttons I want all the observations where it says yes to either of the two checked variables.

I'm trying to write a query that will do this, but Access doesn't support SQL case function and I can't get it to work with the IIF statement.

I want to code something along the lines of:

```
select var1,var2,var3 
from table 
where iif(form!form1!var1=yes and form!form1!var2=no and form!form1!var3=yes,table.var1=yes or table.var3=yes and table.var2=no,...)
```

It seems you can only use iif in certain places. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You can't access form elements directly in a query. You'll have to use a prepared query or concatenate.

Comment: @serakfalcon, it's not true. MS Access queries can get values from opened forms. See: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/304428?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @MaciejLos I stand corrected. For some reason I couldn't get it to work in adodb querydef objects but maybe that's something else entirely...

Comment: I can definitely access form elements because I've already gotten that part to work. The question is how do I access the elements with "or" rather than "and"

Comment: An IIf statement has three parts: expression, truepart, falsepart. A comma separates each part, so if you need various Ands and Ors, use brackets, eg `And (table.var1=yes or table.var3=yes)`. Make another stab at it and then post the whole statement.

Comment: Are 'var1', etc. controls on your form? You mention buttons, but don't say how they are related. If they are controls and are defined as yes/no, or boolean, and you only want YES/TRUE, then why not just have your where clause be: Where (TBL.Var1 = Form!Form1!Var1 and Form!Form1!Var1 = True) or (TBL.Var2 = Form!Form1!Var2 and Form!Form1!Var2 = True) or (TBL.Var3 = Form!Form1!Var3 and Form!Form1!Var3 = True);   Also, hope you really don't have your table named 'Table'!!

Comment: My table is not in fact named table lol

Comment: var1 is a yes/no variable and form!form1!var1 is the button on the form that is related to that yes/no variable

Answer (score 0):

The SQL shown below will return the proper rows if the following steps are taken:

```
SELECT Table1.Var1, Table1.Var2, Table1.Var3, Table1.ID
FROM Table1
WHERE ((([Forms]![frmChildTable]![bVar1] And [var1])=True)) 
    OR ((([Forms]![frmChildTable]![bVar2] And [var2])=True)) 
    OR ((([Forms]![frmChildTable]![bVar3] And [var3])=True));
```

- Create 3 textboxes on the form named bVar1, bVar2, bVar3
- Set the format to Yes/No
- Have your existing three buttons toggle the controls

I assume your use of the word 'button' meant 'Command Button'. If you wanted to use 'Option Buttons', then no code necessary to toggle.